# Yii2 Is it possible to use translation in common dir?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to translate a constants file located in **common/php/** that I use for error messages.

The constants are defined like this:

```
define("CONSTANT_NAME", Yii::t('common/error', 'Error message'));
```

I have the following in **common/config/main.php**:

```
    'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'backend*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@backend/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'it-IT',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'backend' => 'app.php',
                ],
            ],
            'common*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'it-IT',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'common' => 'app.php',
                    'common/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
            ],
            'frontend*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@frontend/messages',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'it-IT',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'frontend' => 'app.php',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

It's working for backend and frontend but it's not working for the constant file located in common. Am I trying to do something that is not possible?

Comment: https://thecodeninja.net/2014/12/i18n-with-yii-2-advanced-template/

Comment: Thank you @Roman but I've already read that. Anyway my configuration is kinda the same. The problem is that I'm not sure whether I can translate strings inside the common dir. 
Of course I have a message folder in common, to which I can access both from frontend and backend but when i try to use **Yii::t('common/error', 'Error message')** in the common directory the messages are always displayed with the source language.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it's not possible, I mean the idea is import translation from common to backend or frontend and use it there

Comment: @Roman Yes I have a list of constants in common/php. We had that even before we translated the application. We include constant file in backend/web/index.php and frontend/web/index.php. 
Then we decided to translate the app but we would like to keep costants in the common dir. So here I am trying this but I'm convincing myself that it's not possible (even if I don't get why).

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to translate from **it-IT** to en-US then add this to your **common/config/main.php**:

```
'sourceLanguage'=>'it-IT',
'language'=>'en-US',
```